# What does CT stand for in CTSESSION cookie name?

Tags: web, single-sign-on, session-cookies

CTSESSION cookie is used in WebSSO to identify a user. I wonder what does CT stand for in the name of the cookie?

I've tried to search CTSESSION word in stackoverflow, but it gives only 5 results and abbreviation of CT is not expanded there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClearTrust. A very old product of the RSA company.